# Pass Regex To JQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

Hi I have following scenario. 
I have working regex but cant pass it to jQuery selectors.
I am trying following.

​`$("#prefix_[\d]{1, 2}_postfix")`

My elements have ids as follows
prefix_10_postfix
prefix_1_postfix

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Note here that in regex `[\d]{1, 2}` can be used as `\d{1,2}`, no need of class and space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use starts with and ends with attribute-value selector

```
$('[id^="prefix_"][id$="_postfix"]')
```

This will select all the elements whose id starts with *prefix_* and ends with *_postfix*.

---

If the page contains many elements whose id starts with `prefix_` and ends with `_postfix` but doesn't match the criteria that in between them should be one or two numbers, ex. `<div id="prefix_tushar_postfix"></div>`, the starts with and ends with selector will not work. In this case `filter` can be used in combination with attribute selectors.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/bcu0utgf/)

```js
var regex = /^prefix_\d{1,2}_postfix$/;

// Narrow down elements by using attribute starts with and ends with selector
$('[id^="prefix_"][id$="_postfix"]').filter(function() {
  
  // filter the elements that passes the regex pattern
  return regex.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prefix_1_postfix">prefix_1_postfix</div>
<div id="prefix_123_postfix">prefix_123_postfix</div>
<div id="prefix_tushar_postfix">prefix_tushar_postfix</div>
<div id="prefix__postfix">prefix__postfix</div>
<div id="prefix_11_postfix">prefix_11_postfix</div>
<div id="prefix_aa_postfix">prefix_aa_postfix</div>
```