# Javascript get length of an array of fields with a array keys in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a simple form with an array in it:

```
<form id='my_form'>
    <input type="text" name="my_array[1]">
    <input type="text" name="my_array[5]">
    <input type="text" name="my_array[6]">
    <input type="text" name="non_array_field">
</form>
```

As you can see the array keys are specified

How can I get the lenght of this array? I can use javascript or jquery

These only works if the array doesn't have keys:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[name='my_array[]']").length
document.formName.elements["my_array[]"].length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [attribute-starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). To select only the elements inside form, use form selector.

> [attr^=value]
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".

```
document.querySelectorAll("#my_form [name^='my_array[']").length
```

```js
var len = document.querySelectorAll('#my_form [name^="my_array["]').length;
console.log(len);
```

```html
<form id='my_form'>
  <input type="text" name="my_array[1]">
  <input type="text" name="my_array[5]">
  <input type="text" name="my_array[6]">
  <input type="text" name="non_array_field">
</form>
```

Using jQuery

[Docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("#my_form [name^='my_array[']").length
```

```js
var len = $('#my_form [name^="my_array["]').length;
console.log(len);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='my_form'>
  <input type="text" name="my_array[1]">
  <input type="text" name="my_array[5]">
  <input type="text" name="my_array[6]">
  <input type="text" name="non_array_field">
</form>
```

Comment: To use regex in selector see [Pass Regex To JQuery Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238616/pass-regex-to-jquery-selector)