# How to select elements by name using RegEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a table with some records, In each row `tr` I have two Textbox in two `TD`,
All textboxes don't have `Id` and `Class`, They just have a `Name`, Their Names Are like below

```
PurchaseDetails[some number].Quantity
PurchaseDetails[some number].PurchasePrice
```

Like:

```
PurchaseDetails[1457160526936].Quantity
PurchaseDetails[1457160526936].PurchasePrice
```

I use below codes but doesn't work:

```
var ProductQuantity = $(this).find("input[name=PurchaseDetails[/^[0-9]+$/].Quantity]").val();
var ProductPurchase = $(this).find("input[name=PurchaseDetails[/^[0-9]+$/].PurchasePrice]").val();
```

my complete html code is :

```
 <tr >                                                        
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="PurchaseDetails[1457161853893].Quantity" ></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="PurchaseDetails[1457161853893].PurchasePrice" ></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: @Tushar Please see updated.

Comment: This is not **complete** code. Perhaps, create live demo.

Comment: ok  , i'm sorry . wait .

Comment: @t please see:  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ufa4sLb7/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one element with that prefix and suffix in the current context(`$(this)`), [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) can be used.

```
$(this)
    .find('input[name^="PurchaseDetails"][name$="Quantity"]').val();
```

Comment: To use `filter()` see [Pass Regex To JQuery Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33238664/2025923)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for filtering using regex

```js
// replace `$('input')` to `$(this).find('input')` to avoid searching in global context

var ProductQuantity = $("input").filter(function() {
  return /^PurchaseDetails\[\d+\]\.Quantity$/.test(this.name);
}).val();
var ProductPurchasePrice = $("input").filter(function() {
  return /^PurchaseDetails\[\d+\]\.PurchasePrice$/.test(this.name);
}).val();

console.log(ProductQuantity, ProductPurchasePrice);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="PurchaseDetails[1457160526936].Quantity" value=1 />
<input name="PurchaseDetails[1457160526936].PurchasePrice" value=2 />
```